# EPUB3, iBooks 1.5, CSS3 and Javascript information

Tags: javascript, css, animation, ibooks, epub3

Ok I'm putting it out there... There is no clear information on the internets about iBooks 1.5, ePUB3 and CSS3 animation being used to create interactive eBooks.

Apple recently featured "The Beatles - Yellow Submarine" ebook and this has some very basic animation, audio and video. I have some great ides for this space however I can't find anywhere how I can create this myself.

I can create a basic eBook with images and video and using tools like "calibre" or "pages" can get them into iBooks but I'm stumped on anything harder using javascript (can I use Jquery etc) and CSS3 animation...

Any ideas where I can find this information????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of the information you are looking for is in the iBookstore Asset Guide, which is available from Apple once you have an iTunes Connect account. For example, Apple recommend using JavaScript to trigger interaction and CSS for the actual animations and transitions. I have heard about someone using jQuery but do not have an example I can point you too.

Liza Daly has a good example (http://blog.threepress.org/2010/06/24/javascript-and-interactivity-in-ibooks/) but be aware that her post is well over a year old and was written with a much earlier version of iBooks in mind.

Please let us know of any good resources you come across.

Comment: Yep it turns out that I actually read the guide cover to cover and it answered 99% of all my questions... but seriously who reads a guide :-). Thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

Some (basic) information about scripting can be found [here](http://idpf.org/epub/30/spec/epub30-changes.html#sec-new-changed-scrp), [here](http://idpf.org/epub/30/spec/epub30-contentdocs.html#sec-scripted-content) and [here](http://idpf.org/epub/30/spec/epub30-contentdocs.html#app-epubReadingSystem). Hope it helps